# How to send simple object in cURL post request

Tags: curl, post, stripe-payments, urlencode

I need to attach a simple object `{foo:"bar"}` to a x-www-form-urlencoded cURL post request. Notice the metadata tag in the example below: How do you encode an object like that? I realize it's not literal JSON, like I have in the request example below.

`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers \
    -u **********************: \
    -d currency=usd \
    -d description='This is a test' \
    -d destination=************* \
    -d metadata='{foo:"bar"}' \
    -d amount=200`

I've also tried `%7B'foo'%3A'bar'%7D` and `foo=bar`

The Stripe API response is always:

`{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Invalid metadata: metadata must be a set of key-value pairs",
    "param": "metadata"
  }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that has trouble with the nesting metadata, the answer is the following...

`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers \
    -u ************: \
    -d currency=usd \
    -d description='This is a test' \
    -d destination=********* \
    -d metadata[foo]=bar \
    -d amount=200`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
-d metadata='{"foto":"bar"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This might work in other scenarios, but the Stripe API doesn't accept that format. What ended up working was ```metadata[foo]=bar```